# windows - copy latest modified files from folder tree to new folder maintaining structure

Tags: windows, batch-file, copy, windows-scripting

I have a huge folder tree with files I occasionally modify. I want a script that goes through that folder tree and copies the latest modified files (let's say the ones modified today) and copies them in new folder placing them in the subfolders they belong. Is there a way to do that with a bat file or third party software?

Comment: You could try [RoboCopy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx)

Comment: i really don't see the reason for the downvote. anyway i found my answer and posted it

Comment: I'd say it's because asking for recommendations for tools is considered off topic. That's also why I only commented because answers for questions recommending tools also tend to get downvoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a free software that did the work. SyncBack Free.